# Como baixar um simples arquivo de texto?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Como eu baixo e pego a `String` contida num arquivo online no Windows Phone 8.1 SDK?

Comment: Fale mais sobre esse arquivo online, é ftp, é uma página html

Comment: É um arquivo FTP, mas pode ser acessado via HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
private async Task<string> DownloadAndReadFile(string url)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```